# Entity framework demo project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My client want Entity framework on next project, I am not getting how to start work on Entity framework... How should i start to implement this in my asp.net mvc application?
if anyone can provide me demo project and some good article to start this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two nice demo applications that I know of:

- [MvcMusicStore](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1)
- [Tailspin Travel](http://tailspintravel.codeplex.com/)   (I used a modified version during a [user group presentation](http://blog.krisvandermast.com/BeingAPimpWithoutSilverlightPresentation.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

A very good tutorial using Entity Framework and MVC can be found in the official ASP.NET MVC website: http://www.asp.net/mvc/samples/mvc-music-store

Answer (score 1):

This [MSDN blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brada/asp-net-mvc-example-application-over-northwind-with-the-entity-framework) can point you in the right direction:

Code for the MSDN Blog can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/)